# Subtleties of Delete procedure by Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC, who can explain?

Tags: entity-framework

It is works:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Delete(int id, Products p) 
{
   DataContext.Products.DeleteObject(
      DataContext.Products.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Id == id));
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And it is works too:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Edit(Products p) 
{
  DataContext.ApplyCurrentValues("Products",p); 
  return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
}
```

But this not working:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Products p)
{
   DataContext.Products.DeleteObject(p);
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you must first `Attach` object before you can delete it:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Products p)
{
   DataContext.Products.Attach(p);
   DataContext.Products.DeleteObject(p);
   DataContext.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The third sample isn't working because the Product that is passed to your method isn't attached to the context and you can't delete an object from a context that the object isn't attached to.

You can either stick with your first example (which is what I prefer because, presumably, I would change my Action method to take a ViewModel object rather than the Entity) or you could attach the object you are receiving:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete(Products p)
{
    DataContext.Products.Attach(p);
    DataContext.Products.DeleteObject(p);
    DataContext.SubmitChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```